# Create User in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My Schema is :

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String},
    city: {type:String},
    accounts: [
        {
            typeA: [
                {
                    isUsed: String,
                    someInfo: String
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            typeB: [
                {
                    isUsed: String,
                    someInfo: String
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

I can insert the document with only name and city. Where:

```
app.get('/createuser', function(req, res){
    var user = req.body;
    var name = req.body.name;
    var city = req.body.city;
    var type = req.body.type;

    User.create(user, function(err, doc){
        if(err) return err;
        else { res.send(doc); }
    }); 
});
```

I want to insert the value in `accounts` based on `var type = req.body.type;`. If the `type = typeA`, i wan the value for `typeA.isUsed = "yes"`
I tried :

```
app.get('/createuser', function(req, res){
    var user = req.body;
    var name = req.body.name;
    var city = req.body.city;
    var type = req.body.type;

    if(type == "typeA"){

        user.accounts.typeA.isUser = "1";
        User.create(user, function(err, doc){
        if(err) return err;
        else { res.send(doc); }
    });
    }
    if(type == "typeB"){

        user.accounts.typeB.isUser = "1";
        User.create(user, function(err, doc){
        if(err) return err;
        else { res.send(doc); }
    }
});
```

But this is not working. How can I achieve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: You are referencing an array as of it were an object. First, when you access `accounts` and second when you access `typeA` and `typeB`. You would have to do something like `user.accounts[0].typeA[i].isUsed`... actually the more I try to parse this data the more I realize that my best advice would be to restructure your data. Without knowing what it is that you are trying to accomplish, that's unfortunately the most I can do for you.

Comment: Im trying to build the document for social logins. So `typeA` is facebook and `typeB` is google. If user authenticates with FB, i want to set `isUsed` in the `typeA` and if its google set `isUsed` for google. but before implementing it i am testing the pseudo code.

Comment: Also, i want the email to be out of fb and google scope in the schema as the same user may use both the options and want to keep it combined. btw, its still not working. :(

Comment: Are the fields different for FB and Google, or just the data that they store? I'm trying to understand why typeA and typeB? Most importantly, what is the `someInfo` field storing?

Comment: I think yes, the fields for FB are a bit different from Google. Some info are the extra fields. Like there may me someinfo1, someinfo2 ... but in the type array and no further arrays.

Comment: Plus, I want to store the info for both, FB and  Google even if the user has same email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    city: String,
    email: String,
    accounts: {
        fbAccount:{
             foo: String,
             bar: String,
             baz: String
           },
          googleAccount:{
            foo: String,
            bar: String
           }
    }
});
```

Okay, this obviously isn't perfect and won't get you exactly what you want, but without more detail it's the best I can do.

You would access googleAccount for instance, like this... `user.accounts.googleAccount.foo`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (.) for the dot between user.accounts

Comment: try quoting them `"user.accounts.googleAccount.foo"`.

Comment: @quaterpi .. thanks a lot. Using a simple `object` works and giving what i want. Thanks again.

Comment: @Somename that's great! Glad I could help. I am curious what the context was when you were getting the SyntaxError: Unexpected token (.)? Depending on the context, quotes may or may not be required.

Answer (score 1):

**Schema**

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    city: String,
    accounts: {
        typeA:{
             isUsed: Boolean,
                   .
        },
        typeB:{
             isUsed: Boolean,
                  .
        },           
    }
});
```

**route.js**

```
var User = require('path/to/user);

app.get('/createuser', function(req, res){

    var user = new User();

    user.name = req.body.name;
    user.city = req.body.city;

    if(req.body.type == "typeA"){
        user.accounts.typeA.isUser = true;
    }
    if(type == "typeB"){
        user.accounts.typeB.isUser = true;
    }

    user.save(function(err, user){
        if(err) return err;
        res.send(user); 
    });
});
```

Above adapt from our code, but I think better schema would be array of accounts per user:

```
accounts: [{
    email: String,
    type: String,
          .
    }],           
}
```

**route.js**

```
user.accounts.email = req.body.email;
user.accounts.type = req.body.type;
```

Comment: I agree that an array of accounts would probably be better. I structured the Schema that way because @Somename said they wanted to keep the email out of the fb google scope.

Comment: I see. I think we should embed email in account. In case, user has same email for both account, It's just a little bit redundant. However, we have advantage in term of flexibility in the case where user has different email.

Comment: If a user has a different email, a new document/user will be created. The email field is unique.